# Google maps: update my map after correct position created point

Tags: google-maps

I try drawing on google maps and I have problem. When I edit position created point google maps duplicate my points and i get two points: old and new.

```
let pointCord = [];    
function createRoute(e) {
const lat = e.latLng.lat();
const lng = e.latLng.lng();

pointCord.push(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));

const flightPathOptions = {
  path: pointCord,
  editable: true,
  draggable: true,
  strokeColor: '#000',
  strokeOpacity: 1.0,
  strokeWeight: 5,
  map
};

flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline(flightPathOptions);
const getPath = flightPath.getPath();

map.addListener('click', createRoute);
```

I try apply this code

```
google.maps.event.addListener(getPath, 'set_at', function(){
   pointCord = getPath.getArray();
   createRoute(e);
});
```

but don't help me. How delete old point and update my map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem it's flightPath inner createRoute. Need your flightPath out your function.

```
    const flightPathOptions = {
      path: pointCord,
      editable: true,
      draggable: true,
      strokeColor: '#000',
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 5,
      map
    };

    flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline(flightPathOptions);
    const getPath = flightPath.getPath();

    function createRoute(e) {
       getPath.push(e.latLng);
    }

    map.addListener('click', createRoute);
```